# Django 3.1 - async views - working with querysets

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-3.1

Since 3.1 (currently beta) Django have support for async views

```
async def myview(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
```

This example will not work - since ORM is not yet async ready

so what's the current workaround ?

you cannot just use sync_to_async with queryset - as they it is not evaluated:

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

async def myview(request):
    users = await sync_to_async(User.objects.all)()
```

so the only way is evaluate queryset inside sync_to_async:

```
async def myview(request):
    users = await sync_to_async(lambda: list(User.objects.all()))()
```

which looks very ugly

any thoughts on how to make it nicer ?

Comment: No need for a lambda : `await sync_to_async(list)(User.objects.all())`

Answer (score 17):

There is a common GOTCHA: Django querysets are lazy evaluated (database query happens only when you start iterating):

so instead - use evaluation (with list):

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

async def myview(request):
    users = await sync_to_async(list)(User.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 7):

From **Django 4.1**, `async for` is supported on all QuerySets:

```
async def myview(request):
    users = [user async for user in User.objects.all()]
```

more info: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/async/#queries-the-orm)

Comment: so the aync version of `User.objects.filter(is_active=True)` is `[user async for user in User.objects.filter(is_active=True)]`? but it returns a list instead of a queryset